# need implementation of Fuzzy Kohonen Networks (Fuzzy self organizing maps)

Tags: som

I have the SOM toolbox with the original implmentation of a Kohonen network. I am looking for a fuzzy kohonen network implmentation. Does anyone have it or know where I can get it?

Answer (score 0):

libraries containing Kohonen implementations in various languages:

Encog Artificial Intelligence Framework for Java

http://code.google.com/p/encog-java/

Encog Artificial Intelligence Framework for DotNet

http://code.google.com/p/encog-cs/

Encog for C/C++/ObjectiveC - Machine Learning Framework

http://code.google.com/p/encog-cpp/

Kohonen Self-Organizing Map Library - C/Python

http://code.google.com/p/ksom/